# Dpinst is showing the UI screen even after sending silent parameters, how to fix that?

Tags: installation, drivers, windows-installer

The OS version:

[image: OS]

The Dpinst window I am seeing:

[image: dpinst]

The command I am using to suppress the window, but not working here.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\IA\Eclipse\FTDI Drivers\dpinst64.exe" /S /Q /SA /LM /SW
```

With or without /Q same issue

Answer (score 0):

we need to provide /SE also to suppress the prompt appearing below.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\IA\Eclipse\FTDI Drivers\dpinst64.exe" /S /Q /SA /LM /SW /SE

[image: driver prompt]